# Select on change, difference between insert a function like parameter or a instruction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know the difference between this sentence:

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
    Manager.doRequest();
}).trigger('change');
```

And this one:

```
$('#select').on('change', Manager.doRequest()).trigger('change');
//or
$('#select').on('change', Manager.doRequest).trigger('change');
```

The first one is executing right, but not the second.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
    Manager.doRequest();
}).trigger('change');
```

The executes the `Manager.doRequest()` function when the `#select` change event fires.

```
$('#select').on('change', Manager.doRequest()).trigger('change');
```

This assigns the returned value of the `Manager.doRequest()` function (which is invoked immediately) to the change handler. This is unlikely to work unless the `doRequest` function returns another function to be executed when the event happens.

```
$('#select').on('change', Manager.doRequest).trigger('change');
```

This is similar to the first example in that it executes the `Manager.doRequest()` function when the `#select` change event fires, however the scope of `this` in the `doRequest` function will be the `#select` element which caused the event.